# How does React handle bundled and source code together in one file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, babeljs, bundling-and-minification

I hope I will make myself clear enough to illustrate my point. Let's say we have a `ui-components` library, which is an external npm repository with bundled react code.
Then, I use that bundled javascript code in my source file in TypeScript e.g.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {SomeComponent} from 'ui-components';

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => (
  <SomeComponent/>
);
```

Since the `ui-components` code already ships to my `node_modules` catalog in a bundled, transpiled form, how does React handle such mix and properly renders the whole html structure? Is there some kind of built-in mechanism that allows react/babel to understand which parts of the source code have been already compiled into pure javascript, and which of them require such step? To be honest, I've been working with React for quite a while and this makes me really confused. I've tried to go through the code myself but i couldn't figure it out on my own, so I will appreciate your help.

Comment: if you're using `create react app` than `webpack` is bundling your code